# Is it possible to compare value to multiple columns in ''In'' clause?

Tags: plsql

```
select m.value
from MY_TABLE m
where m.value in (select m2.some_third_value, m2.some_fourth_value
                  from MY_TABLE_2 m2
                  where m2.first_val member of v_my_array
                  or m2.second_val member of v_my_array_2)
```

Is it possible to write a select similar to this, where `m.value` is compared to two columns and has to match at least one of those? Something like `where m.value in (select m2.first_val, m2.second_val)`. Or is writing two separate selects unavoidable here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. When there are multiple columns in the **IN** clause, there must be the same number of columns in the **WHERE** clause. The pairwise query compares each record in the **WHERE** clause against the records returned by the sub-query. The statement below

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_main m
WHERE  ( m.col_1, m.col_2 ) IN (SELECT s.col_a,
                                       s.col_b
                                FROM   table_sub s)
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_main m
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   table_sub s
               WHERE  m.col_1 = s.col_a
               AND    m.col_2 = s.col_b)
```

The only way to search both columns in one **SELECT** statement would be to **OUTER JOIN** the second table to the first table.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM   table_main m
       LEFT JOIN table_sub s ON (m.col_1 = s.col_a OR m.col_1 = s.col_b)
WHERE  m.col_1 = s.col_a
OR     m.col_1 = s.col_b
```